# Python - Can I use blinker library for this purpose?

Tags: python, flask, blinker

I'm wondering if I can do these jobs with blinker library(or maybe with whatever libraries).

1. I run a web application using Flask and within this application(maybe `app.py`), I define a signal named **updated**(e.g. `blinker.signal('updated')`).
2. In a separate process, I connect(subscribe) any function(I'll call it `subscriber`) to the **updated** signal. And this process runs forever like a daemon.
3. Whenever an **update** occurs on the web side, I want the `subscriber` function to be called.

So I wrote some codes:

*app.py* (Flask application)

```
from flask import Flask
from blinker import signal

app = Flask(__name__)
updated = signal('updated')

@app.route('/update')
def update():
    updated.send('nothing')
    return 'Updated!'
```

*background.py*

```
import time

from app import updated

@updated.connect
def subscriber(*args, **kwargs):
    print('An update occurred on the web side!')

while True:
    print('Waiting for signals...')
    time.sleep(1)
```

And ran the web application with `flask run` command. Now when I visit `localhost:5000/update`, I can see `Updated!` message in browser but I can't see the message `An update occurred on the web side!` from other process.

Is my approach wrong? If it is, how can I do such jobs? Waiting for your answers, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blinker's description [is](https://github.com/jek/blinker):

> A fast Python *in-process* signal/event dispatching system.

Emphasis mine, so no you can't use the library to send signals between two processes.

What can you do instead? Well, the Python Standard Library's documentation has a whole chapter on [Interprocess Communication and Networking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html). It's not clear what you're trying to build, but if you need to build a task queue (with "workers"), for instance, try [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery) or [TaskTiger](https://github.com/closeio/tasktiger). If you do need to actually send messages between processes, something more complex like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) would be appropriate.

Comment: Ah, I've missed that description. Thank you for your clear answer and good suggestions!

Comment: I lost that description too. It's not on the documentation, it can only be seen there on About section (honestly I just found it because deliberately I searched for that).
It should be put more clearly on documentation.